# SQL, Firebase or something else?

Tags: sql, database, firebase, authentication, flutter

I'm trying to build a game-app where:

- the user will be able to login.
- the user (if loged in) will be able to save his progress in the game.

-The stuff that should be saved is:

- an avatar that the user has built
- what questions the user has answered
- how much coins the user has earned and has left.

I have read a few things about primararly SQL and Firebase. Is there a clear distinction between the two or any "rules" on how to chose database?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It totally depends where you want to store "Users Data".

- If you want to store it on the mobile itself, then You should use **persistent database** which is **SQLite**.
- If you do not want to store it on the mobile, but want to store it on a server then you should go for firebase(where your mobile game will require internet).

> Generally, the way you have described your game, people go for SQLite.

Feel free to ask more questions if required.

Comment: Thank you very much :) My goal is to keep it as an off-line game and I don't think it should be a problem to store it on the device. So I reckon SQLite will be the way to go then.